# Converting a nested list to a nested tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

please how can i loop through a nested list get a nested list of tuples out of it for instance loop through pot to get rslt

```
pot = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

I tried

```
b = []

for i in pot:
    for items in i:
        b = zip(pot[0][0:],pot[0][1:])
```

but didnt get the desired output Thanks

Desired Result =

```
rslt = [[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]]
```

Comment: What's the desired result again?

Comment: Just write it all explicitly without using zip and I'm sure you can figure it out.  It's just two levels of loops.

Comment: Desired result is rslt or should appear as rslt. Thanks

Comment: Is it sure that a nested list will contain 4 elements to make it pair as u are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `grouper` [recipe in the itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), you might try something like this (assuming your sublists are the length you have indicated):

```
>>> def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n  # creates a list of n references to the same iterator object (which is exhausted after one iteration)
    return zip(*args)
```

Now you can test it out:

```
>>> pot = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
>>> rslt = []
>>> for sublist in pot:
    rslt.append(grouper(sublist, 2))
>>> rslt
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (7, 8)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a list comprehension:

```
[[(a, b), (c, d)] for a, b, c, d in l]
```